# Sharing constant declarations between Authorize attribute and UI DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-structures

I have a static class where I have declared a set of constants that I use to decorate my [Authorize] attribute. These constant values have no spaces in between, because that's how I am storing my claims in the database.

```
public static class RoleTypes
{
     public const string ProjectManager = "ProjectManager";
     public const string TeamLead = "TeamLead";
}
```

And I am using these constants in the Authorize attribute like this:

```
 [Authorize(Roles= RoleTypes.ProjectManager)]
```

Now, I want to use the same constants to populate a drop down list on my razor page and so, I am populating a Dictionary using reflection on the RoleType class as thus:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAllRoleTypes()

             {

                    var dict =  typeof(RoleTypes)

                      .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)

                      .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly) // constants, not readonly

                      .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(string)) // of type string

                      .ToDictionary(fi => fi.Name, fi => fi.GetValue(null) as String);
                    return dict;

             }
```

But the problem is I need spaces to display between 'Project and Manager', as it would be the Text on the dropdown list item.

How can I achieve sharing one set of constant declarations, across both [Authorize] (without spaces) and on the UI (with spaces)?

What other data structure can I use, as [Authorize] forces us to use constants and I am not allowed to write custom attributes for some reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to split the string on capital letters.

```
private string SplitOnCapital(string input)
{
    var output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && char.IsUpper(input[i]))
        {
            output += " ";
        }
        output += input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

and use it when creating the dictionary.

```
.ToDictionary(fi => fi.Name, fi => SplitOnCapital((string)fi.GetValue(null)));
```

Comment: Thanks @hijinxbassist. I can't wait to try this out tomorrow, as it looks very promising. This is just an incredible answer, as I was breaking my head the whole afternoon and I had never heard of ToTitleCase(). Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, the second option didn't work. My bad. The original question remains. Right now, If I declare the same set of constants twice: once with spaces and the other without, it works fine with the code I posted above, obviously, What I was trying to avoid was to declare the same set of constants twice (once with spaces and once without). I need a data structure. I may try Tuple<string, string, string> tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure if you saw, but I updated my answer a few days ago.  This should work fine for what you are doing.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response, @hijinxbassist, as I just saw this. I implemented this by changing the claim names with an "_" , It is very similar to your solution, as it involves an easy way to manipulate the string. Thanks though!